# Firestore: How to do Collection Group Queries by Doc Ref id instead of field?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The title might be vague. I see the examples where we can do a collection group query to a sub-collection by using a field key. This will force us to make an index. Example:

```
let museums = db.collectionGroup('landmarks').where('type', '==', 'museum');
museums.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
    console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
  });
});
```

However, in my implementation the documents in the "landmarks" sub-collection have specific id's. So I don't need to query the fields. I just want to get a document which I have the doc ref id from a collecton group. Is there something like this?:

```
let museums = db.collectionGroup('landmarks\' + docId).get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
    console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
  });
});
```

And would this save us from indexing a field?

Comment: Do you mean that in the different `landmarks` subcollection you have documents that have the same doc Id and you want to query all of them?

Comment: Renauld exactly. that's what I am looking for. Let's say Each Post have Comments subcollections. And the doc id of these Comments collections are the userid of the commentator. I want to query a specific userid for all the comments he/she has made for all Posts. I made up this example now, i know it doesn't make sense but roll with it for the sake of argument:)